# Same random seed for different dependent variables in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, cross-validation, random-variable, lasso

Consider dependent variables $Y_1, ..., Y_n$, some of which may be correlated. For each dependent variable, I want to use machine learning with sample splits for model selection. Clearly, for each dependent variable, the sample splits should be random. However, across dependent variables, is there any need for the sample splits to be random?

In particular, purely for the sake of convenience, I want to set the same random seed for each dependent variable. In either theory or practice, will this bias my analyses? If it helps, the machine learning method I'm using is Lasso.

Comment: How are you going to select your model?

Comment: @gunes It's a bit complicated, but for simplicity consider the standard case where I select the model using cross-validation for each dependent variable and choose the set of controls and regularization parameter which minimize the mean squared error.

Comment: We can handle complicated. In particular, I am curious why you are not training a multivariate model.

Comment: @Dave By multivariate model, do you mean multiple dependent variables or multiple covariates? The models I am using have one dependent variable and multiple covariates per model.

Comment: You have multiple dependent variables.

Comment: @Dave I see. The software (Stata) I am using does not allow for multiple dependent variables, and it is important that I use Stata for this particular project.